# My PC starts up with black screen

Tags: hardware-failure

My PC just crashed, and now I can't get it to start up.

I was watching something on my PC. All of a sudden my screen started flickering at the top and bottom of the screen. After about 10 seconds, the screen turned white, and after about 3 seconds it turned black.

After killing the power and turning it on again, everything seems to start up (keyboard lighting works, fans runs), the screen "wakes up" but immediately after that the monitor shows "no input" and goes into standby again. After a while the PC tries to restart (or at least, my keyboard lighting turns off and on again), after that restart the monitor is not asleep, but remains black.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use an external graphics card? If yes, try removing it so your monitor can plug in to the motherboard graphics port. Try boring and see what happens. Next thing may be your CPU overheating.

Comment: Problem solved? Computer boots as normal and works for a decent time with no side effects? Then yes, the graphics card is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments the problem has been identified as the external graphics adapter has failed. Removing the graphics card and using the onboard graphics should confirm this as the system should boot and operate normally.